# Xamarin remove app title

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm struggling with the dumbest thing (I guess I'm just not used to the Xamarin Designer).

How can I remove the title of my app ? It keeps showing up but it is not in my Layout Source.

I want to remove this whole part but can't figure out how.
In C# Winforms or WPF I would have selected the whole window or screen and then accessed the main window properties but in this case, I can only select the controls I added (buttons and labels) and not the whole screen or the title.

> [image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I remember, in your Activity Class you have to remove the Attribute label there so that it won't have a title. I currently don't have Xamarin with me right now but I'm pretty sure there is an attribute above the class name that sets the Title.

**UPDATE from phadaphunk:**

Remove android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" from the manifest file will completely remove the title

**UPDATE**

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

At the time I wrote the answer, the best answers that are given now are available to the framework. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't remember those API being available at the time of this writing.

Comment: @phadaphunk Updating the answer. I only answered what was on top of my head. :P

Comment: answer by Ibrahim `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` seems better

Comment: But where is this `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`??

Comment: 2021 This is not working anymore. Obsolete!

Answer (score 37):

Write this in the `OnCreate` method just after `SetContentView`:

```
ActionBar.Hide();
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't change it in Title theme, it will accept previous version ui.
After `OnCreate`

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
        base.OnCreate(bundle); //
        Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle); //This will Hide the title Bar
   }
```

Alternatively, you could add

```
 NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

to your constructor

Comment: 2021 This is not working anymore!

Answer (score 10):

The option which to me seems the simplest is to edit the `Activity` attribute and use a *default* style (rather than a custom one, as suggested by Mina Fawzy):

```
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar", ...)]
```

If you want to remove the status bar too then use

```
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen", ...)]
```

Comment: Peter Taylor, you just saved me!! I am developing in Xamarin, and I have done everything recommended on Xamarin forums, at Microsoft, etc. but it was your recommendation that finally worked! THIS: [Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen", ...)] is what worked for me. I added that theme to the parent TAG in my styles.xml and it finally made my SplashScreen activity work perfectly.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by create custom style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

         <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

And here how you can use it in your activity:

```
  [Activity(Label = "ActivityLabel", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
```

Comment: 2021 Nope not workin anymore!

Answer (score 3):

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Is the best method.

Comment: already accepted answer also give the same piece of code.. your answer any difference than accepted answer?

Comment: Accepted answer copied this solution in the UPDATE.

Comment: 2021 Does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

In my case I dont't need any Title, I just want an ActionBar with some Tabs so I wrote:

```
RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
```

And after SetContentView:

```
ActionBar.Title = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:`SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: if you want to hide `ActionBar` completely just `SupportActionBar.Hide()`, no other option worked for me. The Activity also has `ActionBar` property which was null in my case maybe because I'm deriving my Activity from `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: 2021 None of these solutions are working!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the title bar, I just changed the "Style.xml" file:

Add this line in  below other items:

```
<item name="windowNotitle">true</item>
```

This will remove the title bar from the "AppTheme", you can also create a custom theme next to it in  and set it in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

[2021] You can set the theme as following:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to app style (Resources/values/styles.xml):

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Should look like:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`under your ContentPage

It works in the latest versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Lots of expectable answers!

However, just in case if it's still not working because let's say you're setting custom views. Try `ActionBar.Title = null;`

Comment: 2021 It's obsolete

Answer (score -1):

`SupportActionBar.Hide();` worked to hide the entire title bar for me.